# Problema para conectar proyecto de Visual Studio a base de datos MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

Mi problema es el siguiente, y no logro encontrar solución.

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL, la cual quiero gestionar desde mi aplicación.

Tengo un proyecto en C# con Visual Studio, en el que estoy utilizando la arquitectura MVVM, y estoy tratando de utilizar la utilidad Entity Framework para que se conecte a la base de datos, lea su estructura y genere automáticamente la capa de clases que representa el modelo.

Para ello, he creado un directorio en mi proyecto, y he añadido un nuevo elemento de tipo "ADO.NET Entity Data Model". Elijo la primera opción, que es "EF Designer desde base de datos". A continuación se me abre la ventana que me permite elegir la conexión y la configuración con la base de datos. Y aquí es donde me encuentro con el problema.

Entre las opciones disponibles, sólo me aparecen las de Microsoft SQL Server, y no aparece el conector a MySQL.

Tengo instalado el "MySQL Tools for Visual Studio" y el "Connector/NET", puedo gestionar la base de datos desde Visual Studio utilizando el explorador de servidores, y también puedo compilar y ejecutar perfectamente cualquier aplicación que ya tenga la capa del modelo generada. Pero no puedo generar yo mismo, personalmente, esta capa. En el asistente que se supone que me generará el modelo no me aparece la opción de configurar una base de datos de tipo MySQL.

Lo más frustrante de todo esto, es que he comentado este problema con algunos compañeros, y cuando replico los mismos pasos desde sus editores, en la lista de conexiones SÍ aparece el MySQL. Pero en la mía no.

¿Alguien sabría decirme qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias!

PD: Adjunto la ventana en la que se supone que debo elegir la conexión con MySQL, la cual no aparece.

[image: Visual Studio 2017]

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16879451)

Comment: tal vez esto te pueda ayudar, tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione con este video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7UPAWFg2lk

Answer (score 5):

Prueba a instalar las siguientes versiones:

mysql-connector-net-6.9.10

mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.7

A mi me pasaba exactamente lo mismo, tenía instalada una versión superior del connector, la desinstalé e instalé esta que te digo y funcionó perfecto!

Irene.

Comment: Concuerdo con esta respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias. Por lo visto ese era el problema, con MySQL estar a la última no es muy efectivo.

Nota: He tenido que instalarlo exactamente en ese orden, primero el connector y luego el for visual studio, al revés no funciona.